# Override Property with different DataType

Tags: vb.net, class, inheritance, types, overriding

How can I override a property from an inherited class but use a different return type?

I am working with a class set up like this:

```
Public MustInherit Class foo
    Public MustOverride Property Value As Object
End Class
```

I want to inherit this class but have the Value property return different type:

```
Public Class foo_string
    Inherits foo

    Public Overrides Property Value As String
End Class

Public Class foo_date
    Inherits foo

    Public Overrides Property Value As Date
End Class
```

This gives me an error: "'Public Overrides Property Value As String' cannot override 'Public MustOverride Property Value As Object' because they differ by their return types."

I can remove the property from the base class and only specify it in the subclasses, but I am wondering if there is another way to make it work.

I am learning about class hierarchy but yet to master it, so I will accept if you think what I'm trying to do makes no sense or that I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Depending on exactly what you want, you might be able to achieve it by making `foo` a [Generic Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, but it is probably not a good idea.

```
Public MustInherit Class fooBase(Of T)
    Public MustOverride Property Value As T   
End Class

Public Class FooBaseA
    Inherits fooBase(Of String)

    Public Overrides Property Value As String
End Class
```

Usage:

```
Dim foo As New FooBaseA
```

This is another option:

```
Public Interface FooValue(Of T)
    Property Value As T
End Interface

Public Class fooA
    Implements FooValue(Of String)

    Public Property Value As String Implements FooValue(Of String).Value
End Class
```

The problem is that you do not want to have to have code to check what Type each object is in order for the code to know how to use a property:

```
Dim fa As New FooA
Dim fb As New FooB

If TypeOf fb Is FooB Then
    Console.WriteLine(fb.Value.DayOfWeek)
End If

' or:
If fb.Value.GetType Is GetType(DateTime) Then
    Console.WriteLine(fb.Value.DayOfWeek)
End If
```

If the data type is different, they probably deserve different names, separate properties and to be implemented on the derived classes. `Text` is an obvious choice for the string version.  It somewhat depends on the actual classes, but I'd be inclined to avoid this.